# Open Workbook from SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I need to open an AddIn that is stored on a SharePoint location with https, to check if it is a newer version than the one locally stored. But

```
Set AddInRemote = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=AddInRemoteLocation, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
```

always returns nothing and does not present any error message. The AddInRemoteLocation looks something like this:

```
https://example.com/corp/folder/file.xla
```

Is it even possible to open the Workbook like this? If yes what do I do wrong? If not, is there another way?

Comment: I have a similar situation where I open from SharePoint, but I keep a second log file available with the dates listed.  My filenames are listed as "yyyymmdd TEMPLATE.xlsx."  In doing this, I first find the last date in the log, then use that to open up the latest version.  Essentially, when you check that log file, you can have it compare the latest date to the latest date of the local file, then it opens the highest based on an IF statement.  If your naming structure is similar to mine, you could have VBA take left(name,8) and compare based on the name, then open.

Comment: I just realized if the file is a .xlsx or .xlsm file vba opens it without problems. I really hate that kind of undocumented behavior.
Thanks for your idea Cyril, I guess I will implement it like that